# Showing custom address attribute in sales order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, customer-address

I would like to add additional text field as `Landmark` in `Billing Address` and `Shipping Address`.

So I created a simple module as below

**app/etc/modules/**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ucs_CustomField>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Ucs_CustomField>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Ucs/CustomField/etc/config.xml**

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ucs_CustomField>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Ucs_CustomField>
    </modules>
    <global>
         <resources>
            <landmark>
                <setup>
                    <module>Ucs_CustomField</module>
                    <class>Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </landmark>
        </resources>
        <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <landmark>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </landmark>
            </sales_convert_quote>
            <customer_address>
                <landmark>
                    <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                </landmark>
            </customer_address>
        </fieldsets>
    </global>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Ucs/CustomField/sql/landmark/mysql4-install-0.0.1.php**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute('customer_address', 'landmark', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Landmark',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1
));
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer_address', 'landmark')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address'))
    ->save();

$tablequote = $this->getTable('sales/quote_address');
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `landmark` varchar(255) NOT NULL");

$tablequote = $this->getTable('sales/order_address');
$installer->run("ALTER TABLE  $tablequote ADD  `landmark` varchar(255) NOT NULL");

$installer->endSetup();
```

After Creating this, I modified `System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Address Template`

For Text added `{{depend landmark}}Landmark {{var landmark}}{{/depend}}`

Text One Line `, {{depend landmark}}Landmark {{var landmark}}{{/depend}}`..

But From admin side in `Sales->Order` Grid or Customer side my account View Order, Print order, I cant see newly created field?

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a mistake in `config.xml`

```
         <fieldsets>
            <sales_convert_quote>
                <landmark>
                    <to_order>*</to_order>
                </landmark>
            </sales_convert_quote>
            <customer_address>
                <landmark>
                    <to_quote_address>*</to_quote_address>
                    <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
                </landmark>
            </customer_address>
            <sales_convert_quote_address>
                <landmark>
                    <to_order_address>*</to_order_address>
                    <to_customer_address>*</to_customer_address>
                </landmark>
            </sales_convert_quote_address>
        </fieldsets>
```

After making this change in `config.xml` it is working fine.

**For Magento 2:**

```
app/code/<Vendor_Name>/<Customer_Extension>/etc/fieldset.xml
```

Create an `xml` like above and place the below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:DataObject/etc/fieldset.xsd">
  <scope id="global">
      <fieldset id="sales_convert_quote_address">
       <field name="custom_field">
          <aspect name="to_order"/>
       </field>
      </fieldset>
      </scope>
</config>
```

Comment: i have same issue in magento 2. how should i fix there?

Comment: @sam please refer the updated answer